# infinity, p2 and p1 Norm and its associated unit ball that has negative y values

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

ok I try to phrase it in a way that is not redundant with other questions.

I am surprised with the shapes that the norms take on BUT only as far as their extension into the -y regions go. How can that be if norms are non-negative?

Why does the unit "ball" that becomes a square for the infinity norm dive under the x axis, likewise the ball for p2 when norm would correspond to only the upper half of the picture that is usually given for it...

Comment: The point ball is the set of all the points whose norm is 1 meaning all $x$ such that $N(x)=1$. So for example using standard Euclidean norm, $N(1)=1$ AND $N(-1)=1$. Therefore here is a negative number included in the unit ball. The unit ball is NOT composed of the norm values themselves.

Comment: Thank you, I see your rationale but could you perhaps disambiguate. I believe the notation confused me. I sort of expected N to take x and y as input, or if one input it would make sense to me if it was complex. So if you say N(-1), silly question but how should I interpret that -1?

Comment: ok I think I got it. It was quite stupid of me. Of course what's graphed it always only the input pairs (Euclidean space) that fulfill the requirement N(x) as you said. I suppose N(x) is more generic than using (x,y) or z depending on where we are. But in the concrete example that you gave, shouldn't there be still a N(0,1) = 1 or N(1,0) in the Euclidean space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment was a little sloppy. Let $N$ be a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the unit ball is the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose norm is one. So for example if we consider the Euclidean norm, then

$$N(-1,0)=N(0,-1)=N(0,1)=N(1,0)=N\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=1$$

so all five of these points are on the unit ball. Since the norm is defined for all of the points in the plane, the input to the norm function can be anything, positive, zero, negative. The output must always be nonnegative.

To disambiguate my comment, when I wrote the comment I was thinking only of $\mathbb{R}$ with $N(x)=|x|$ to show that the input to a norm function can be negative. For a generic dimension, we can always use $N(\vec{x})$ where $\vec{x}$ is a vector of whatever type we need it to be.

Comment: Thank you again, the clarification makes perfect sense.